# Electrostatic Potential Difference Between Points

Tags: electrostatics, potential

I had a doubt that in a uniform electric field, how will a positive test charge be moved radially from its initial position( Say A) to some point say B in the electric field.If we exert an external force to displace the particle from A to B, is there anyway to displace it without change in kinetic energy as I feel that there would always be a component of force that would accelarate the particle ? I ask this to calculate the potential difference between the two points ( by calculating the work done )

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping KE constant during all the movement is the same as having only the normal to velocity component of the force. So, your external force should cancel out any tangential forces along the way. What you consider is possible if your initial velocity is on the line that connects $A$ and $B$ pointing towards $B$. In general, the possibility will depend on the points $A$ and $B$ and the field.